# MVC Models variable not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The project is a calculator only with buttons and one label field for the expression and output.

After pressing any button, there is a POST to one of two functions. Here is the Controller

```
public class CalculatorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddToExpresion(string _char, CalculatorViewModel CVM)
    {
        CVM.Expression += _char;
        return View("Index", CVM);
    }
}
```

And here is the View

```html
@model WebApplication1.Models.CalculatorViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Calculator";
}

<h2>Calculator</h2>

<form asp-controller="Calculator" asp-action="Calculate" method="post">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label asp-for="Expression">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Expression)</label>
                <input asp-for="Expression" type="hidden" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" asp-action="AddToExpresion" asp-route-_char="(">
                (
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" asp-action="AddToExpresion" asp-route-_char=")" >
                )
            </button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" asp-action="AddToExpresion" asp-route-_char="%">
                %
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" value="AC">
                AC
            </button>
        </div>
..
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that when AddToExpression is called, at first the Expression is null (correctly so) and then after second try it's still null (should be the previous char) Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not bound to an input, a value is not submitted with your form. So, if you need to retain the characters from a previous submission, you need to add an input to your form. Not familiar with the newer helper syntax, but this should work:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label asp-for="Expression">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Expression)</label>
    <input asp-for="Expression" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Comment: I will test this tomorrow and see if this works! Going to mark this as the answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters in the AddToExpresion method must match the fields that are created in the view.
There is différent ways to access parameters in the view:

1. Create a parameter that corresponds to the model of the view as you did but the _char parameter must match a field in the view.
2. Or use the FormCollection object to access to the sent parameters by the form.
3. Or use a object custom binding that inherits from the IModelBinder object.

Cordialement